# Как задать pythonencoding =utf-8 программно?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

PYTHON 3, как задать PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8 программно? То есть без

$ export  PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', buffering=1)
sys.stderr = open(sys.stderr.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', buffering=1)
```